# JS script failing when DOM anchor href property is not present on the html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a little JS script that gets called when I click on a button. The script does several things among which - if present - take the href of a link and fill in the #id_instagram input field with it.

PROBLEM: the 'a href' link is not alway present on the page. When not present, the first JS line that goes to fetch its href will clearly not find anything causing the whole JS script to fail and not run. How can I say something like "if a href there, do this, otherwise do that"?

Thanks

HTML

```
<a href="www.instagram.com/link"  id="instagramPath"></a>

<input id="#id_instagram"></input>
```

JS

```
var instagramPath = document.getElementById('instagramPath').href;
document.querySelector('#id_instagram').value = instagramPath;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is not present all the time (or on every page load), you can handle this with an if condition:

```
var instagramLink = document.getElementById('instagramPath');

// this will prevent errors if instagramLink does not exist
if (instagramLink) {
    document.querySelector('#id_instagram').value = instagramLink.href;
}
```

Comment: That's awesome. Thank you very much guys.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get the Node using getElementById. Defensive coding is always welcome, so you can check if the node isnt empty or null or undefined. If it exists, you can then get the attribute using the getAttribute method of the Element object. This will be null if not found.

```
var instagramPathNode = document.getElementById('instagramPath');

// if the node exists
if(instagramPathNode){
   var instagramPath = instagramPathNode.getAttribute("href");
   if(instagramPath){
     //href exists and is not empty
     // do processing here
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Emmanuel great solution, but maybe you better add an explanation.